# Attach GLX contexts with different visuals to the same X Window subsequently

Tags: linux, opengl, x11, glx

I'm trying to create a GLX context, attach it to a X Window, detach and destroy it again, then create another GLX context with a different Visual and attach it to the same window.

```c
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Descriptions for the visuals to try - if both are equal, the example works
static int attr_sets[][3] = {
        { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None },
        { GLX_RGBA, None }
};

Display *dpy;
XVisualInfo *vi;
GLXContext cxt;
Window wnd;
size_t i;

void fail(const char *m) { fprintf(stderr, "fail: %s #%lu\n", m, i+1); abort(); }

int main(void) {
    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    wnd = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, 0), 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        if (!(vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, 0, attr_sets[1]))) fail("choose");
        if (!(cxt = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, None, True))) fail("create");
        XFree(vi);
        if (!glXMakeCurrent(dpy, wnd, cxt)) fail("attach");
        if (!glXMakeCurrent(dpy, wnd, 0)) fail("detach");
        glXDestroyContext(dpy, cxt);
    }
    XDestroyWindow(dpy, wnd);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

This example works on Mesa 10.5.2 with Intel graphics but fails on AMD fglrx 12.104 when the second context is attached (`fail: attach #2`).

What is the reason for this error? Is this forbidden by specification or is it a driver error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `XCreateSimpleWindow` you'll see, that it's actually just a wrapper around `XCreateWindow`. `XCreateWindow` in turn will use the visual of it's parent.

Now X11 visuals are only half the story. When you attach a OpenGL context to a Drawable for the first time, the visual (and for the more advanced features also its FBConfig) of that Drawable *may* become refined, so that later on only OpenGL contexts compatible with that configurations can be attached.

In short once a Drawables Visual/FBConfig has been pinned down, only OpenGL contexts compatible to it can be attached. See the error's defined for `glXMakeCurrent`, notably

> BadMatch is generated if drawable was not created with the same X
>   screen and visual as ctx. It is also generated if drawable is None and
>   ctx is not NULL.

Normally when using GLX you'd use [`glXCreateWindow`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXCreateWindow.xml) to create a OpenGL exclusive subwindow in your main window, which Visual/FBConfig you can set without affecting your main window.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Is it generally safe to _not_ use glXCreateWindow if the visual does not change?

Comment: @trion: A regular window should do as well. However using glXCreateWindow is the recommended way to go. That being said I know of certain OpenGL implementations (specifically a certain range of versions) where using glXCreateWindow with a specific set of Visual/FBConfigs actually results in either the client, the server or both segfaulting; this is a bug however and eventually it got fixed, so you should not worry about it. My personal stance on such bugs is, that I don't work around them to increase the pressure on the developers of the buggy software to fix their issues.